# Preeventing QGraphicsItem's itemChanged

Tags: python, qt, signals, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsItem that the user can drag around. I want to keep the item in the upper right quadrant of my scene, so I overrode mouseMoveEvent like this:

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if self.x() < 0:
        self.setPos(0, self.y())
    if self.y() + self.rect().height() > 0:
        self.setPos(self.x(), -self.rect().height())
```

Works like a charm, so far so good.

Now I use the itemChanged to kick off calculations when the item moves. Although I made my item stand still when it reaches my defined boundary, itemChanged gets called also when my mouse is in the 'forbidden zone', which is understandable.
I would like to block this behavior based on the above checks. Since QGraphicsItem is not a QObject, blockSignals does not work here. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Don't perform the check before emitting the event, but in the receiving function before you process anything

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer use ItemChange(...) when working with scene view framework. Avoid using mouseMoveEvent.

To disable itemChange, you can set item to not movable.

```
{
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges , false);
...
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges , true);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the advice not to use mouseMoveEvent. That fails when I select more than one item and move them around, because only the one I'm dragging receives the mouseMoveEvents, the ones that are going along for the ride happily cross the quadrant boundaries. I'm now checking and adjusting the ôbject position in itemChange(), and to avoid recursion I return the adjusted position. That sort of works, but my objects jump and flicker, since they are actually visibly moved outside the given boundaries and then retroactively adjusted in itemChange. How can I avoid that?

Comment: There are two calls related to flicking, QGraphicsView::setCacheMode(QGraphicsView::CacheBackground);
QGraphicsView::setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::BoundingRectViewportUpdate);